Permission denied when executing binary files on android targetSdkVersion>28
i have an application that creates a ssh connection tunnel for traffic forwarding. but it's working perfectly on targetSdkVersion 28 and below. but on atargetSdkVersion>28 when running(executing) the following commands(when running binary files), it raise error 126 OR Permission denied.
i don't know what exactly has changed in api version 29( permissions or /data/data/ or whatever). the error is unclear.
    protected static String BASE = "/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a";
    protected static String BASE_BIN = "/bin";
    ssh_return_val = Util.runChainFireCommand(
                            ((key_switch && !enc_ssh_key) ? "" : BASE + BASE_BIN + "/sshpass -p \"" + password_text + "\" ")
                                    + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/ssh " + server_text + " -p " + port_number + " -l " + user_text
                                    + " -NT -g -D " + Util.localSocksPort + (dns_switch?" -L 127.0.0.1:8163:"+dns_server+":53":"")
                                    + forward_string
                                    + (key_switch ? " -i \"" + BASE + "/id_rsa\"" : "")
                                    + (compress ? " -C" : "")
                                    + " -o \"ProxyCommand " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/korkscrew"
                                    + (iptables_switch ? "" : " --ancillaryfile " + BASE + "/sshfd_file")
                                    + (proxy ? " --proxyhost " + proxy_host
                                    + " --proxyport " + proxy_port + " --desthost %h --destport %p"
                                    + " --headerfile " + BASE + "/header_file" + "\""
                                    : " --directconnection --desthost %h --destport %p\"")
                                    + " -o \"KeepAlive yes\" -o \"ServerAliveInterval 15\""
                                    + " -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking=no\" -o \"GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null\"", false, true);
                }

Logcat:
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/sshpass: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH-] 126
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH+] /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox killall -9 korkscrew;/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox killall -9 ssh;/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox killall -9 tun2socks/data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox killall pdnsd
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] START
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH+] /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox killall pdnsd; echo $?
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/com.staf621.ki4a/ki4a/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH-] 126

I have attached an image of /data/data/packagename/ files and contents and permissions of the binary files. See image
on targetSdkVersion<=28, it works perfectly, but on targetSdkVersion>28 it catches error 126 and Permission denied when running binary files

What are the minimum and target SDK versions of your app? Are you running the exact same .apk on both devices?

min is 21 and target was 28 and i change it to 30

yes. one apk file when i run on android 14(api ava 34) i got these error. but less that android 14 works fine. something has changed in android 14 that prevent executing these binary files

I think the problem is related to you changing the target SDK version, and not to the actual version of the device it's running on. To confirm that, can you try running the target SDK 30 build on Android 13 and see what happens there?

before i change anything target sdk was 28 and it works on all andorid version but wasn't working on android 14. now i change it to 30, again works on all android ver except 14

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i realized something. when i change target SDK upper than 28, it says permission denied and not work. for 28 and less it works

targetSdkVersion 28 is the last one before Android 10. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission is what changed after that:

Execution of files from the writable app home directory is a W^X violation. Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's APK file.
Untrusted apps that target Android 10 cannot invoke execve() directly on files within the app's home directory.
In addition, apps that target Android 10 cannot in-memory modify executable code from files which have been opened with dlopen() and expect those changes to be written through to disk, because the library cannot have been mapped PROT_EXEC through a writable file descriptor. This includes any shared object (.so) files with text relocations.

And that's exactly what you're trying to do. This is the exact same problem that Termux ran into that stopped them from being able to publish any updates to the Play Store; see https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Termux-and-Android-10 and https://github.com/termux-play-store for more about that.

I put the binary files into the APK file, but it still raise error

I have set targetSdkVersion=28 and get APK output and run the app on android 10,11,12,13 without problem. so i the problem is android 10 why the APK works on even android 13 BUT NOT 14
